# C semantics: "col -= size--" having ++ or -- operating in an expression

Tags: c, syntax

Real short and simple:

say `col = 10`, `size = 8`. Then the following is executed:

```
col -= size--;
```

So does size get subtracted to 7 before doing the subtraction on col (so col = 3)? Or col = 2?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`size--` yields the previous value of `size`, so this is equivalent to:

```
col -= size;
-- size;
```

Comment: This may be a little nitpicky, but I would recommend not using the increment or decrement operator other than by themselves, for the very reason that this question was asked. It makes the intent of the code less clear, creates a sweet spot for off-by-one errors, and is a bit of a mental speed bump even for experienced coders.

Answer (score 1):

`size--` decrements size and returns the original value (`--size` would decrement and return the new value).

The right expression is evaluated before the left, so the value of the right would be subtracted from `col`.

If `col = 10` and `size = 8`, then after `col -= size--`, `size` would equal 7 and `col` would equal 2.

Answer (score 1):

When `++` or `--` appears after the operand, the value is returned first and then it is incremented/decremented. If it appears before, it's the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to that should be `col = 8`. How?

`col -= size--;` is interpreted like this:

IN COMPILER'S HEAD:

Compiler: mmhmm, so `size--` eh? Ok fine, what's `col`? `10`? And `size` is .. `8`? Fine set `col` to `2` after that operation and then decrement `size`.

If it was: `col -= --size;` it would be:

Compiler: mmhmm, so `--size` eh? Ok fine, what's `size`? `8`? Set it to `7`.. and `col` is `10`? so the answer after that subtraction is `col = 3`. And so the compiler thinks its the boss.